# Convert html-json into actual json

Tags: python, json

How would I convert the following in an html page to an actual json object I can parse from?

```
<script src=\"http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/i18n/en-us/translations-219ee4e300884b27b7e875b76cdd956b.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/script>\n          <script src=\"http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_core-c4b64baae3fbc0e521f2421421b5fbd7.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/script>\n              <script src=\"http://static.huluim.com/huluguru/application_framework-83ca0d7c85063f8e535d65f6fcb7ebfa.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/script>\n            <script type='text/javascript'>\n    window.jsLoaded.frameworkloadedCallbacks.push(function(){\n      
window._preloadedFastStartVideo = {\"id\": 786746, \"eid\": \"AXbfrprlxGzisLBNlTdzMw\", 
\"title\": \"10.0 Earthquake\", \"video_type\": \"feature_film\", \"content_id\": \"60551582\"}
```

Essentially I would like to be able to do:

```
>>>  _preloadedFastStartVideo['id']
786746
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us the context of where and how in the page it was given escaped that way. Is this inside a script tag? A CDATA context? Something else?

Comment: Literal two-character `\n` sequences? I actually doubt that. Is this what you're getting by typing `varname` at the Python prompt? That's different from what you'd get from `print varname`; Interactively running `>>> varname` is the same as `print repr(varname)`, which is very different from `print str(varname)`; the latter is how you'd get literal content appropriate to paste in a StackOverflow question.

Comment: ...and if your literal data just has quotes with no backslashes before them (being, then, valid JSON), then you should be able to pass it directly to `json.loads()`.

Comment: ...well, you actually _could_ provide repr()-escaped content here, and nobody would have trouble understanding it, but it's very very important that you make it clear to the reader whether something is repr() output or literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json.loads('*your json here*')

```
import json
json.loads('{\"id\": 786746, \"eid\": \"AXbfrprlxGzisLBNlTdzMw\", \"title\": \"10.0 Earthquake\", \"video_type\": \"feature_film\", \"content_id\": \"60551582\"}')
```

returning

```
{u'content_id': u'60551582', u'title': u'10.0 Earthquake', u'id': 786746, u'video_type': u'feature_film', u'eid': u'AXbfrprlxGzisLBNlTdzMw'}
```

if you want to grab the string you need from the string you provided you can use something like this :

```
import re
instr = re.sub("\n","",string.split("window._preloadedFastStartVideo =")[1])
```

follow up with

```
d = json.loads(instr)
```